# Using FirebaseJobDispatcher

Tags: android, firebase-job-dispatcher

I'm trying to use the `FirebaseJobDispatcher` for the first time and I got the code below from an example.

```
            FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
            Job job = FirebaseJobDispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                    .setTag("testing job")
                    .setService(SmsDeleterJobService.class)
                    .setReplaceCurrent(true)
                    .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
                    .build();

            dispatcher.mustSchedule(job);
```

However Android studio has it underlined with the following message

```
Variable 'dispatcher' initializer 'new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this))' is redundant less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: This inspection points out the cases where a variable value is never used after its assignment, i.e.:  - the variable never gets read after assignment OR
  - the value is always overwritten with another assignment before the next variable read OR  - the variable initializer is redundant (for one of the above two reasons)
```

I looked at a few examples and they were all like this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `FirebaseJobDispatcher` is no longer being supported and you should move to `WorkManager`

Comment: @tyczj unfortunately all the examples I'm finding are in Kotlin. Do you know any in Java?

Comment: Just look at the docs https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager